# Complex Home Networking Setup Advice

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I need a hand with my home network setup. It's a little complex for me and I'm having some problems.

The main problem is we can't seem to get above 25mb on a speed test despite having a 100mb plan. I know there are 5+ of us connected at a time - but even when no one is downloading (checked by looking at Virgin Media connection status) it's not performing well.

Here is a diagram of how the house is setup

[image]

Some of our wired connections show the SSID of one of our wireless routers in Network Settings, when that wireless router is just an access point.

[image]

"Da Beaufort Middle" is the SSID of Wireless Point A, bbt my PC (JONNERZ-PC) is connected by wire to the switch.

Another problem is that when connected to one of our wireless routers, it doesn't let me see other network computers, whereas others do.

Both access points have DHCP disabled.

Comment: can you show us speed tests, so we are on the same page of what 25 MB means.

Comment: DHCP should only be enabled on a single device on the network. What do you have the switch plugged into? a modem? a router? Have you tested with only one device plugged into the ISP device? I suggest to just bypass your network altogether and test with only one device connected to the ISP device, that will let you know if it is your network, or something else. If you can, test from where the wires come in off the street (the NID) - that will bypass inside wiring as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would setup -troubleshoot my own home network
(Windows based computers - Fiber Modem/Router combo provided by my ISP, 4 windows desktop computers connected by Ethernet. 3 windows laptops, 1 mac book pro and one HP netbook (running Linux Mint) all connected to the internet by Wi-Fi connection)

I would start like this:

**Make sure you know the IP address of the Master of Your Network,**

I will assume in this case it's your virgin media box, (or in my case my fiber modem/router combo)

Questions to ask: Is the Virgin Media box A Fiber Modem and a Router? Does it have DHCP and NAT turned on by default?

**FIRST RESET YOUR MODEM/ROUTER, WAIT FOR IT TO MAKE AN INTERNET CONNECTION THEN...**

Plug a windows laptop directly in to the modem/router) with an Ethernet cable (make sure you unplug all other devices from the other Ethernet ports on the modem/router and tell every body that the internet will be down for an hour while you fix this). Type ipconfig /renew, at a command prompt (start - run - cmd - at the command prompt type: ipconfig /renew, if this takes a long time and the ip address for the machine and the default gateway start with 169, you should check your cables) If the command works you will get your current ip address is and the ip address of your default gateway. Most likely something like this

**my pc's ip address (as reported by ipconfig) is 192.168.2.XX
and The default gateway (as reported by ipconfig) is: 192.168.2.1 (my modem/router static ip address - not my internet ip address)**

**now check if the internet is working on that laptop**, if it's working check your modem/router by going to the ip address of your default gateway in your web browser (as most fiber modem router have a built in web server that lets you program it with a web browser), check your status page, check your network setup page, take note of the routers ip address (it should match the default gateway, and it will be the default DHCP server, but more on this later) take a look at the routers DHCP IP ADDRESS RANGE TABLE, mine is like this 192.168.2.10 - 192.168.2.100 (that means that I can use any ip address below 192.168.2.10 (but not 192.168.2.1) or any ip address above 192.168.2.100 and below 192.168.2.255 as static IP addresses (more on this later), also look for the subnet, it should be something like 255.255.255.0 or something like that. Don't forget to go to your router setup page and setup a Wi-Fi password using WPA2, and please set your SSD (name of Wi-Fi network), check if your router is using G or N or AC for Wi-Fi. If your are using other Wi-Fi Access Point please also take a note of the main routers W-Fi channel

**check your equipment**

Make sure all Ethernet connected machines (and router & switches) support 10/100/1000 or all 10 or all 100 or all 1000 meg network speed (this is very important if you use anything old that can not automatically switch to the right speed)

make sure all your Wi-Fi equipment supports WPA2 and/or G or N or AC depending on your Wi-Fi router setup

**Check your Ethernet Cables with a cheap but Good tester**

(or go out and buy new cables)

**try everything in AUTO MODE FIRST**

go to each machine or device and make sure the TCP/IP settings are in auto (on everything)

make sure that all access points extra on the system have DHCH turned off, have the Default gateway set to the main router and have a different SSD, password and a different channel than the main router.

**boot up your network the right way.**

Turn all your devices off, turn on the main router first, wait for it to make an internet connection, turn on all your other switches and access points (switches for a home network should be dumb switches), next turn on your fastest newest windows computer first (this important for windows networking, but more on that later), then turn on the other machines and see if the Ethernet connected machines have internet (if you type ipconfig on these machines (if the internet works) then each machine will have a different ip address in the main routers DHCP range and will say the Default Gateway is the ip address of the main router. Make sure the wireless devices can see your network SSD and can connect with your WPA2 Wi-Fi password, make sure they get a unique ip address from the main dhcp server (ipconfig) and they point their gateway and/or dhcp server to the address of the main router. If everything works great, if not then the next step.

**Try everything in static ip mode.**

you know the ip address of the default Gateway 192.168.2.1 (you can use this for the DHCP server address too) you know the dhcp table range, you know you can use the range 192.168.2.101 - 192.168.2.254 for static ip addresses, you know your subnet mask 255.255.255.0, you know the Wi-Fi SSD and you know the Wi-Fi password

now you know enough to go to each device and manually set up the tcp/ip connection, give every device a manual and different ip addresses:

192.168.2.110 - dad's pc,

192.168.2.120 - mom's pc,

192.168.2.130 - HP printer,

192.168.2.140 - extra access point,

192.168.2.150 - mac book pro,

**if still no joy....
Call your ISP**

now you can call your ISP, disconnect everything form the isp's modem/router except for one laptop connected by Ethernet, reset your modem, turn everything else off and call your ISP, remember most ISP will not support equipment that is not their own, so be ready before you call, if the internet works on that one laptop connected tor the modem/router (be sure to reset that laptops tcp/ip setting back to default), your ISP might say that the Internet is working and they can't help you.

test the internet, if it still does not work everywhere, then

**Be prepared to replace old equipment**

"After spending all night with my network I determined that my old Linksys switch was not working, so tomorrow I will get a new one"

**I hope this helps**

Larry Hyman

Comment: at one time I had three access points on my home network

Comment: you could take your small laptop with you as you set this up. This way you can check that all the hardware stuff is working.

Comment: I fixed the post above